# Removing a HTML class from specific elements in an alternating row table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a script that detects if a row is odd and adds a HTML class named 'alt'.

Some rows in this table are chapters and should have the 'chapter' class assigned (I have just a few chapter rows so the class is assigned manually). I want to remove/toggle the 'alt' class for these elements (if they fall in the odd range).

The script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var row=0;
    $('table.features-table tbody tr').each(function() {
        row++;
        if(row%2==0) {
          $(this).addClass('alt');
                  }

        if(document.getElementById('table.features-table tbody tr').className("chapter")) {
          $(this).removeClass('alt');
                }       
            });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what's your question? :D

Comment: I want to remove/toggle the 'alt' class for these elements(if they fall in the odd range). How do I do this?.. obviously the included script is incorrect.

Comment: the script detecting the odd rows is working fine... but I'm really not sure about my scripts logic AND syntax when it comes to replacing/toggling the alt class if my row has the 'chapter' class already assigned

Comment: there is a function called `toggle();` in jquery, try that

Comment: well I used removeClass because I'm running the addClass if statement first, but I'll look at toggle().
Question: for my second if statement, is the syntax correct or I managed to mix it up a little bit to much?

Comment: well the toggle adds class if its not there, and removes it if its there. for the second syntax, you are simply checking if classname chapter exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var row=0;
    $('table.features-table tbody tr').each(function() {
        row++;
        if((row % 2 == 0) && ($(this).children('.chapter').length == 0)) {
          $(this).addClass('alt');
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but nope... doesn't work and the adding of the 'alt' class doesn't work anymore either.

Comment: @seb did it run at all? I think there was an missing `});` in the original answer, deleted too much of your original code...

Comment: If I understand correctly your script is adding an exception for className('chapter') to the addClass. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I added the }); before running the script and also isn't the correct syntax: className('chapter') not className("chapter")?

Comment: My idea was to add the 'alt' class only if the row don't have 'chapter' class already (and `row%2==0`), thought thats what youre after?

Comment: yep... that's the idea... unfortunately it's not working... but the logic looks solid to me

Comment: Well, does it give some error or it just doesn't do what yore looking for? In thta case what it does?

Comment: @seb See the updated script - I think it should use `hasClass()` instead of `className()`

Comment: firebug says: $(this).className is not a function
[Break On This Error] if(row%2==0 && !($(this).className("chapter"))) {

Comment: here's the test page in case you wanna look: http://www.marquise-tech.com/web_test/table-test/

Comment: Well, seems to work? Every other row is in different style... there is no rows with 'chapter' style? Using FF3.

Comment: yep... I tried it... it still adds the 'alt' class on the 'chapter'

Comment: nope... the chapter is the field with the big cyan text and as you can see it's marked in gray(that's the 'alt' class doing it's job)

Comment: @seb OK, the problem is that the 'chapter' class is on the `td` not on the `tr`! See the updated script, added `.first()` which should select first child element... looking for better solution.

Comment: updated... doesn't work... but it's a good idea with selecting the first child... looking into a solution as well based on your catalyst.